# Bash Script - Logic Refactoring

Tags: bash, algorithm, loops, refactoring

Reformulating original question:

**End goal:**

- List item

using some sort of looping process run a single command multiple times

**It needs:**

- made in bash
- do not repeat myself
- command requires 2 variables

**File Names:**

- DEPLOY_FILE_1
- DEPLOY_FILE_2
- KUBE_A
- KUBE_B

**The requirement is to run a command with parameters and variables in the same command**

- These variables must be updated as soon as the first loop is done
- Command is in the following form:

> SOME_COMMAND ARGS $VARIABLE_A ARGS $VARIABLE_B

- $VARIABLE_A points to file: KUBE_A
- KUBE_A has 2 lines ( but it could have more in the near future ):

  <auth_factor_1>

  <auth_factor_2>
- $VARIABLE_B points to file DEPLOY_FILE_1
- DEPLOY_FILE_1 has multiple lines following this pattern and naming convention:

  <name_1>

  <name_2>

  <name_3>

  <name_N>
- The same command described above needs to run as many times as lines are defined in DEPLOY_FILE_1
- Once done values in $VARIABLE_A and $VARIABLE_B must be updated to be:
- $VARIABLE_A points to file: KUBE_B
- $VARIABLE_B points to file: DEPLOY_FILE_2

**This is what I could came up with so far:**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

KC_A=$(cat "/k8s-config/kubeconfig-A")
KC_B=$(cat "/k8s-config/kubeconfig-B)
def ARRAY_KC=(KC_A KC_B)

APP_A=$(cat "/tmp/configuration-files/testing-A-scale-down")
APP_B=$(cat "/tmp/configuration-files/testing-B-scale-down")
def ARRAY_APP=(APP_A APP_B)

CURRENT_NAMESPACE="alpha"
WAITING_PERIOD_BEFORE_NEXT_SCALE="2"

for i in "${$ARRAY_APP[@]}";
    do
        for j in "${$ARRAY_KC[@]}";
            do
                for k in "${$i[@]}";
                    do
            kubectl --kubeconfig $j -n $CURRENT_NAMESPACE scale deploy $k --replicas=$REPLICASET_NUMBER
        done
    done
done
```

**Notes:**

- While this is around K8, it could be what ever other command
- I'd like the focus to be in both: logic and bash syntax
- It does not work.

Hopefully, this is a little bit more clear.  Would you please provide some assistance?

Comment: STOP_SHOUTING!  Although it is common, there is no (good) reason to use all caps for your variable names.

Comment: It looks like the only difference between the two loops is `CDE_KUBECONFIG` vs. `NON_CDE_KUBECONFIG`.  So define a variable appropriately and use it in a single loop.

Comment: I do not understand what should be the end goal. Do not guess programming - instead re-read bash introduction until you know what to write. `Each of them have files that need to be processed independently` So independently, or looping one over the other?  What should be the resulting sequence of commands executed?

Comment: thanks @KamilCuk, I have just reformulated the whole thing, hoping it makes sense

Comment: But why so many "points to" variables? Why not just read both files? `apps=$(cat firstfile secondfile)`. `must be updated to be:` I still am not sure if you want to run for every possible combinations of contents of both files or for pairs of equivalent lines from both files? Please post file contents and commands to execute - leave implementation details to implementation. You want to run `SOMECOMMAND <auth_factor_1> <name1>` `SOMECOMMAND <auth_factor_1> <name2>` `SOMECOMMAND <auth_factor_1> <name3>` etc. `SOMECOMMAND <auth_factor_2> <name1>` `SOMECOMMAND <auth_factor_2> <name2>` etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it too complicated.

```
cat /tmp/configuration-files/testing-{A,B}-scale-down |
while IFS= read -r auth_factor; do
   cat /k8s-config/kubeconfig-{A,B} |
   while IFS= read -r name; do
       SOME_COMMAND ARGS "$name" ARGS "$auth_factor"
   done
done
```

You may want to read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 . `{A,B}` is just a https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion shorthand hare.